# How to identify which GMSMarker was tapped - iOS, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm quite new to Swift and i'm trying to better understand Google Maps API. I'm building a simple app that shows images when markers on panoramaView are tapped through didTapMarker method. Since each marker should show a different images, i'm trying to find a way to identify which marker has been tapped, a sort of marker tag. 
All suggestions are welcome.

Down here is a prototype of the code with 2 markers and 2 images. Not really sure how to do it, but didTapMarker method should show `randomImage` when `marker` is tapped and `randomImage2` when `marker2` is tapped. So far it only shows `randomImage` when both `marker` and `marker1` are tapped.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSPanoramaViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var viewStreet: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var randomImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var randomImage2: UIImageView!

var panoView: GMSPanoramaView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    randomImage.hidden = true
    randomImage2.hidden = true

    let panoView = GMSPanoramaView(frame: CGRectMake(200, 200, 400, 400))
    panoView.delegate = self
    panoView.moveNearCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.732, longitude: 150.312))

    viewStreet.addSubview(panoView)
    viewStreet.sendSubviewToBack(panoView)

    let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.732, longitude: 150.312)
    let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
    marker.panoramaView = panoView

    let position2 = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.732, longitude: 150.311)
    let marker2 = GMSMarker(position: position2)
    marker2.panoramaView = panoView
}

func panoramaView(panoramaView: GMSPanoramaView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    randomImage.hidden = false
    randomImage2.hidden = true
    return true
}
}
```

EDIT: solved, thanks to everyone, i'm adding a trivial example on how to do it then.

```
 marker.userData = "example"
```

Then `didTapMarker` method is always called when a marker is tapped, but `randomImage` 's propriety is set to false only when the marker tapped is the one above.

```
 func panoramaView(panoramaView: GMSPanoramaView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    if marker.userData as? String == "example" {
         randomImage.hidden = false
    }
    return true
}
```

Code can be improved making use of a dictionary to handle multiple markers but it's up to you. :)

Comment: One approach is to use your GMSMarker as a key to a `dictionary[GMSMarker:UIImageView]`

Comment: @Paulw11 got it, thank you!

Comment: You can set the `userData` property on the `GMSMarker` to something (eg the image to display, or the ID of an image, etc).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

put the data of that marker in userData of that marker. Make use of that that whenever marker is tapped in didTapInfoWindowOfMarker api.

Comment: So `marker.userData = randomImage`, ok. Then what should i do? I cannot use method `didTapInfoWindowOfMarker` cause i'm placing markers in PanoramaView which does not support it as far as i know. Ty and pardon, i'm still learning.

Comment: Looks like you could use `panoramaView:didTapMarker:` on `GMSPanoramaViewDelegate`.

Comment: @SaxonDruce ty for info, solved then. I've edited the first post with a sample. :)

Comment: Marker userdata null returns when pushing another vc and returning to previous vc. How to solve it.Help me.